する and す in Shogun? （連体形　vs　終止形）
I understand this is a Modern Japanese Exchange, but this would be the best place to ask, I believe.
I am watching the new Shogun series with japanese subtitles and want to clear up my confusion regarding the archaic endings. From my own research, the japanese being used is Late Middle Japanese. My confusion stems (no pun intended) from both the 終止形　and 連体形 conjugations being used as sentence final.
On ep1 at 22:20, take this line, being spoken by the same person:

聞いております


ご心中お察し申し上げまする

So why is the second line using the 連体形 without a noun following? The only dictionary I have is weblio's classical japanese dictionary, which is not quite the same thing!

As I understand, the Japanese used in it is fairly standard 時代劇 stuff, which is more like 'modern Japanese with classic flavour'

The まする can be considered as 終止形 : what is ございまする?
